# Scrape number data website in every single date of url

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website along the time from 2002 today. Each has its set of numbers. I turned on the inspect, it looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="chu17 need_blank">42</td>
    <td class="chu17 need_blank">46</td>
    <td class="chu17 need_blank">46</td>
    <td class="chu17 need_blank">46</td>
    <td class="chu17 need_blank">49</td>
    <td class="chu17 need_blank">49</td>
    <td class="chu17 need_blank">61</td>
    <td class="chu17 need_blank">62</td>
    <td class="chu17 need_blank">69</td>
</tr>
```

I want to get those numbers before the `</td>` and print it in a .csv file. Here is the python code I am working on:

```
import datetime


urls = []

sdate = datetime.date(2002, 1, 5)
edate = datetime.date.today()

delta = edate - sdate

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    day = sdate + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    day = day.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    urls.append('https://website.php?date=' + day)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as data: 
    file = csv.writer(data)
```

The code will replace every single day on website url from 5-1-2002. I want it to be: In each day the program will gather (scrape) numbers on that HTML code like above, and once it's done the gathering it will go to the next day and do the gathering numbers set of that next day and so on.

How to do that?

Comment: You could probably use [Beautiful Soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: You could use [Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) for fetching the website, [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html), [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [lxml](https://lxml.de) for parsing the html and something like [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for running the script daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use BeautifulSoup to parse and get your data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
    <tr>
        <td class="chu17 need_blank">42</td>
        <td class="chu17 need_blank">46</td>
        <td class="chu17 need_blank">46</td>
        <td class="chu17 need_blank">46</td>
        <td class="chu17 need_blank">49</td>
        <td class="chu17 need_blank">49</td>
        <td class="chu17 need_blank">61</td>
        <td class="chu17 need_blank">62</td>
        <td class="chu17 need_blank">69</td>
    </tr>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
numbers = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'chu17 need_blank'})
for number in numbers:
    print(number.text)
```